# rockmongo not working despite having mongodb driver for php

Tags: php, mongodb, rockmongo

I have installed php7.0 in ubuntu 16.04
I installed the driver as shown here http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
$ cd mongo-php-driver
$ git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make all -j 5
$ sudo make install
```

When I tried to open rockmongo from browser,It is showing

```
    To make things right, you must
 install php_mongo module. Here for installation documents on PHP.net.
```

Also in the index.php of rockmongo, I put `die` and found that 
the line

```
if (!class_exists("Mongo") && !class_exists("MongoClient"))
```

is returning false

sudo pecl search mongo
returned

```
Retrieving data...0%
.Matched packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=======================================
Package Stable/(Latest) Local
mongo   1.6.14 (stable)       MongoDB database driver
mongodb 1.1.7 (stable)        MongoDB driver for PHP
```

I have also included the extension for php.ini

and also did

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

[image: php.info]

I ran `sudo pecl install mongodb`

which gave this result

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongodb-1.1.7
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rockmongo doesn't seem to be compatible with PHP 7 and new `mongodb` driver, but you can follow instructions [from here](https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo/issues/117#issuecomment-221881423) to make it work.